# SUPEE-6285 patch, what has been changed?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-6285

OK, somebody has to ask this: today, 7/7/2015 a new security patch for Magento < 1.9.2 has been released.

> **update your shops ASAP!**

But what has been changed? Are there known exploits of the covered security issues? What's the worst that could have happened?

And is there anything that can break? Like with SUPEE-5994 where it wasn't possible to apply the patch if the downloader directory was missing...

Comment: A LOT. The patch file alone is over 1,100 lines with about 350 additions and 100 removals. Manual template edits will need to be made in ~8 frontend templates if you have overridden them in your package/theme

Comment: Here is a good article http://blog.philwinkle.com/supee-6285-broken-down/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As already mentioned, the patched vulnerabilities are described in detail on this official page (new merchant docs): http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html

### Summary

> #### This bundle includes protection against the following security-related issues:
>
> - Customer Information Leak via RSS and Privilege Escalation
> - Request Forgery in Magento Connect Leads to Code Execution
> - Cross-site Scripting in Wishlist
> - Cross-site Scripting in Cart
> - Store Path Disclosure
> - Permissions on Log Files too Broad
> - Cross-site Scripting in Admin
> - Cross-site Scripting in Orders RSS

---

After patching a few shops, this is what I gathered:

### Theme patches

Some theme files have been patched with added escaping to prevent possible XSS attacks:

- `checkout/cart.phtml`
- `checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`
- `checkout/onepage/failure.phtml`
- `rss/order/details.phtml`
- `wishlist/email/rss.phtml`

If your theme(s) contain any of these templates, or if you made modifications directly in `base/default` (good luck, you are screwed), then you need to patch them manually:

1. in the checkout templates, replace all occurences of

   ```
   $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()
   ```

   with

   ```
   Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl())
   ```
2. in `wishlist/email/rss.phtml`, replace

   ```
   $this->helper('wishlist')->getCustomerName()
   ```

   with

   ```
   Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($this->helper('wishlist')->getCustomerName())
   ```
3. In `rss/order/details.phtml`, replace

   ```
   <?php echo $this->__('Customer Name: %s', $_order->getCustomerFirstname()?$_order->getCustomerName():$_order->getBillingAddress()->getName()) ?><br />
   <?php echo $this->__('Purchased From: %s', $_order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName()) ?><br />
   ```

   with

   ```
   <?php $customerName = $_order->getCustomerFirstname() ? $_order->getCustomerName() : $_order->getBillingAddress()->getName(); ?>
   <?php echo $this->__('Customer Name: %s', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($customerName)) ?><br />
   <?php echo $this->__('Purchased From: %s', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($_order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName())) ?><br />
   ```

### Permissions

`.htaccess` files have been added to `downloader/Maged` and `downloader/lib` to disallow direct access to source files. If you use nginx, you need to add these rules to achieve the same (thx to [Ben Lessani](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73616/243) for this one):

```
location /downloader/Maged/ { deny all; }
location /downloader/lib/   { deny all; }
```

But I recommend to exclude `downloader` from deployments to a live system system anyway, in this case you don't need to take action.

### Admin Privileges (ACL)

If you use restricted admin accounts, some menus of third party extensions might not work anymore for them. The reason is that the default return value of `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_isAllowed()` has been changed from `true` to `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin')`. Extensions that do not override this method in their admin controllers because they don't use the ACL, now need the **"ALL"** privilege.

The only solution is to patch the extensions and add this method to all their admin controllers:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```

Or if they actually have an ACL resource defined in `etc/adminhtml.xml`:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}
```

(you can see that the patch does the same for `Phoenix_Moneybookers` in older Magento versions like 1.7 where this extension was included)

For a more detailed perspective on this issue and an explanation how to define missing ACL resources, see: [Access Denied errors after installing SUPEE-6285](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/73646/243)

### Possible errors while applying patch

1. **Message:**

   ```
   can't find file to patch at input line 899
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
   |index 982ad5a..2bf6b37 100644
   |--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
   |+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored
   ```

   **Reason:** the `default/modern` theme was removed from the installation

   **Solution:** Add `app/design/frontend/default/modern` from a fresh Magento download (should be the same version as your shop). You can also use this mirror: https://github.com/firegento/magento. Then after applying the patch successfully you may remove the theme again.
2. **Message**

   ```
   patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
   can't find file to patch at input line 915
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/Maged/Controller.php downloader/Maged/Controller.php
   |index aa9d705..32755d7 100644
   |--- downloader/Maged/Controller.php
   |+++ downloader/Maged/Controller.php
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   5 out of 5 hunks ignored
   can't find file to patch at input line 976
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
   |index 18020eb..7013c94 100644
   |--- downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
   |+++ downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   2 out of 2 hunks ignored
   patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
   can't find file to patch at input line 1020
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
   |index 9cca5a6..f42e74e 100644
   |--- downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
   |+++ downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   3 out of 3 hunks ignored
   can't find file to patch at input line 1049
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
   |index f74c3df..86aa51b 100644
   |--- downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
   |+++ downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored
   can't find file to patch at input line 1061
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/template/login.phtml downloader/template/login.phtml
   |index 6e4cd2c..dbbeda8 100644
   |--- downloader/template/login.phtml
   |+++ downloader/template/login.phtml
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored
   can't find file to patch at input line 1073
   Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
   The text leading up to this was:
   --------------------------
   |diff --git downloader/template/settings.phtml downloader/template/settings.phtml
   |index 13551ac..47ab411 100644
   |--- downloader/template/settings.phtml
   |+++ downloader/template/settings.phtml
   --------------------------
   File to patch:
   Skip this patch? [y]
   Skipping patch.
   1 out of 1 hunk ignored
   ```

   **Reason:** the `downloader` directory was removed from the installation

   **Solution:** Add `downloader` from a fresh Magento download (should be the same version as your shop). You can also use this mirror: https://github.com/firegento/magento. Then after applying the patch successfully you may remove the directory again.
3. **Message:** Something similar to

   ```
   checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 97 (different line endings).
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
   checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
   checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 29 (different line endings).
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
   checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
   checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
   Hunk #1 FAILED at 25 (different line endings).
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
   ```

   **Reason:** the files are stored with `\r\n` (CRLF, Windows line break) or `\r` (CR, Mac line break) instead of `\n` (LF, Unix line break).

   **Solution:** Simply convert the line breaks, your text editor or IDE should be capable of this.

Comment: As this seems to be a major patch, would you agree that shops running 1.9.x would now be better off upgrading to 1.9.2.0 which includes this patch?

Comment: I didn't update any shop to 1.9.2.0 yet but there seem to be some additional pitfalls and updates should be tested more carefully anyways. I would still recommend to install the patch first.

Comment: In our team we developed a extension just for our use and after this patch I realized some of the admin controllers weren't implementing the ``_isAllowed`` method. Luckily we did have ACL in the module and no additional action was required aside from adding the method. Also, I did encounter that first error message with the ``default/modern`` theme that had been moved (I also found the culprit thanks to Git). +1 for that

Comment: Some excellent stuff here. When I went to update my cart.phtml, I compared my version with that in base and noticed your edit seems slightly wrong. The new line from the patch file is: <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 7):

Via @ http://blog.philwinkle.com/supee-6285-broken-down/

> Generally this involves adding an _isAllowed protected method which
>   returns a boolean. Sometimes this boolean is a result of an ACL check,
>   as with the update to
>   Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController. Sometimes
>   this is hard-coded to true, as with
>   Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php

After I have added:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/config');
}
```

To one of 3rd Party Controller's that Admin Section started to "work" again...

So we will get another Magento Patch soon? This seems to be a bigger issue...

Comment: Please see my answer. Giving the restricted roles the "Dashboard" privilege will allow access to third party sections without own ACL resource again.

Comment: *Magento 1.8*: Checked that (had that right's "ON") - same story: *Access denied*.
Yes I have log out first and log in login after :)

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the configuration for "admin", it actually only returns true for users with all privilieges. It is true that many extensions will need to be patched. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This or as I wrote @ http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285 we might need to write general Override in app/code/local for Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_isAllowed()
<pre>
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/config');
    }
</pre>

Comment: If "system/config" as default permission works for you.. depends on the merchant I guess

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of community / local extensions you’re going to want to pay particular attention to this change in SUPEE-6285 which affects `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` and is around line 666 depending on your patch version (this is EE 1.14.0.1 patchfile):

```
protected function _isAllowed()
    {
-        return true;
+        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin');
    }
```

All custom modules which do not implement their own admin resources are affected by the change above and access will be denied unless the admin user in question has full admin privileges.

If you look elsewhere in the patch you will see that a lot of the included core modules have been updated however this is likely to affect a lot of third party modules so pay particular attention to test any third party extensions in your site post patch to check you can still access them!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the [patch release page](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/patch-releases-2015.html) has been updated with info on what it affects.

I have yet to install on a production site and test

Comment: I've installed it on Dev server and it worked fine, so pushed it to production. Everything seemed to work fine, until some of our product & sales admins tried using Magento admin - these users have restricted role permissions via the 'user role editor' in Magento, they were frequented with access denied errors on some areas of the admin area website which use 3rd-party plugins. My main admin account still works fine on all of these... I'm looking into it still

Answer (score 0):

The full list of modified files after applying the patch is also available in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`

Answer (score 0):

In my case for third party modules, adding below code to the adminhtml controllers worked:

```
protected function _isAllowed()

{
     return true;
}
```