# Applied PATCH_SUPEE-6285 - Do I need to do anything else?

Tags: template, magento-1.6, patches

After being prompted to install the new patch I went ahead and did so straight away.

But now I've gone back and looked at the .sh file I noticed there is changes being made to template files.

I had a custom theme and I also have a onestep checkout extension installed on my site, do I need to apply the patch to those somehow or do I not need to worry?

Comment: it looks like that ACL is broken with this patch, lower users can not work in admin anymore with some 3rd party extensions :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a series of changes you need to make in addition to just running the patch.

*I've used the 1.9.1.1 patch as an example here, but sadly, the patches differ dependent on release.*

---

## Custom template files

If you have modified or overridden the `base/default` template with your own package/design, then you'll need to manually apply the patches as necessary to the following.

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`,

```
- <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
+ <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
```

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml`,

```
- <p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?></p>
+ <p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl())) ?></p>
```

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml`

```
-<p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?></p>
+<p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl())) ?></p>
```

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml`,

```
- <?php echo $this->__('Customer Name: %s', $_order->getCustomerFirstname()?$_order->getCustomerName():$_order->getBillingAddress()->getName()) ?><br />
- <?php echo $this->__('Purchased From: %s', $_order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName()) ?><br />
+ <?php $customerName = $_order->getCustomerFirstname() ? $_order->getCustomerName() : $_order->getBillingAddress()->getName(); ?>
+ <?php echo $this->__('Customer Name: %s', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($customerName)) ?><br />
+ <?php echo $this->__('Purchased From: %s', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($_order->getStore()->getGroup()->getName())) ?><br />
```

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml`,

```
- <?php echo $this->__("RSS link to %s's wishlist",$this->helper('wishlist')->getCustomerName()) ?>
+ <?php echo $this->__("RSS link to %s's wishlist", Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($this->helper('wishlist')->getCustomerName())) ?>
```

In `app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml`,

```
- <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
+ <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
```

---

## `.htaccess` rules

**If you aren't using a `.htaccess` compatbile web server**, then you'll need to manually add the following deny rules.

For **Nginx**,

```
location /downloader/Maged/ { deny all; }
location /downloader/lib/   { deny all; }
```

---

## File permissions

If the user of your web server PHP process isn't the owner of the document root and relies on group permissions, and the `var/report` or `var/log` directories are removed - you will encounter issues with the new default file permissions.

Eg. In the following scenario,

```
PHP User:        www-data
Doc Root User:   sonassi
Doc Root Group:  www-data
www-data members: sonassi, www-data
```

The revised default file permissions of `0750`,  will strip write permissions from the group - which will prohibit your web server from being able to write to the directory.

Equally, if you rely on the `everyone` permission, all access will be stripped.

Comment: It seems like the only file I needed to change was cart.phtml.
All the others do not exist in my theme template files so they should use the default ones that have already been patched.

My server does use .htaccess so that's all good.
And I'll have to see about the file permissions, not sure on that one

Comment: why there is quoteescape around the string "continue shopping "?  was that added by error (I mean by them, I saw it exists in the patch) but other strings not surrounded with the same.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the changes that have been made to the template files. If your custom theme contains these templates (which is most likely with the `cart.phtml` template), you have to apply the same changes **manually** in the theme's templates.

Comment: I checked the checkout extension files and it's file structure is like this.

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\onestepcheckout.

Whereas the patch changes the file in
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/

So the files like cart.phtml and noItems.phtml and failure.phtml do not exist in my extension

Comment: Checkout extension usually don't change the cart template, so that's okay. But it is important that you check if your theme overrides these templates. If not, those from base/default are used and everything is fine

Comment: Yeah my theme does override the defaults I think.
app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml