# SUPEE-6285 and Adminhtml Controller

Tags: adminhtml, configuration, payment-methods, payment-gateway, patches

I currently have an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31428425/4793675) with a bounty on the Stack Exchange website but I feel like I get a lot more inside information in this community due the more people with experience in Magento.

The latest patch [SUPEE-6285](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/73646) does not throw a Access Denied error but produces a 404 Not Found when I am trying to use a `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` Controller.

This functionallity did work before the above mentioned patch.

The code where I think the problem lies. Feel free to look inside the [whole code](https://github.com/icepay/Magento/tree/master/app).

<kbd>app/code/community/Icepay/IceAdvanced/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Paymentmethods.php</kbd>

```php
class Icepay_IceAdvanced_AjaxController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected $webservice = null;

    public function iceWebservice()
    {
        if ($this->webservice == null)
            $this->webservice = new Icepay_IceAdvanced_Model_Paymentmethods();
        return $this->webservice;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function get_paymentmethodsAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($this->iceWebservice()->retrieveAdminGrid($this->getRequest()->get("store"))));
    }

    public function save_paymentmethodAction()
    {
        $adv_sql = Mage::getSingleton('iceadvanced/mysql4_iceAdvanced');

        $reference = $this->getRequest()->getPost("reference");
        $scopeID = $this->getRequest()->getPost("store");

        if (!isset($reference))
            return;

        $adv_sql->setScope($scopeID);

        $settings = Mage::helper("iceadvanced")->getPaymentmethodExtraSettings();

        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost("active_issuers")) {
            $issuers = explode(",", $this->getRequest()->getPost("active_issuers"));
            if (count($issuers) >= 1)
                array_push($settings, "active_issuers"); //At least 1 issuer active is required
        }

        foreach ($settings as $setting) {
            $adv_sql->saveConfigValue($reference, $setting, $this->getRequest()->getPost($setting));
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(sprintf($this->__("%s settings have been saved."), $this->getRequest()->getPost("name")));
    }

}
```

Then a block in Adminhtml gets this function.

<kbd>app/code/community/Icepay/IceAdvanced/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Paymentmethods.php</kbd>

```php
class Icepay_IceAdvanced_Block_Adminhtml_Grid_PaymentMethods extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface {

    protected $_element;
    protected $_scope;
    protected $_ajaxLoadPaymentMethodURL;
    protected $_ajaxSavePaymentMethodURL;
    protected $_ajaxGetPaymentMethodsURL;
    protected $debug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_scope = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::helper("icecore")->getStoreFromRequest())->getId();
        $this->_ajaxLoadPaymentMethodURL = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('icepayadvanced/config/index/paymentmethod/{{pm_code}}', array('_secure' => true, 'scope' => $this->_scope));
        $this->_ajaxSavePaymentMethodURL = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('icepayadvanced/ajax/save_paymentmethod', array('_secure' => true, 'scope' => $this->_scope));
        $this->_ajaxGetPaymentMethodsURL = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('icepayadvanced/ajax/get_paymentmethods', array('_secure' => true));

        $this->setTemplate('icepayadvanced/grid_paymentmethods.phtml');
    }

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setElement($element);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

    public function setElement(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->_element = $element;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getElement()
    {
        return $this->_element;
    }

    public function getJS($uri)
    {
        return Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS, true) . $uri;
    }

    public function getPaymentmethods()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('iceadvanced/mysql4_iceAdvanced')->getAdminPaymentmethodConfigForStore($this->_scope);
    }

    public function getAddButtonHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('add_button');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('icecore')->__('Get paymentmethods'),
            'onclick' => 'return ICEPAY.retrieveFromICEPAY()',
            'class' => 'add'
        ));
        $button->setName('add_tier_price_item_button');

        $this->setChild('add_button', $button);

        if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.7.0.0', '<')) {
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('js_css', 'prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');
        } else {
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addItem('skin_css', 'lib/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css');
        }

        $this->getLayout()
                ->getBlock('head')
                ->addItem('js_css', 'prototype/windows/themes/default.css');

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

And the configuration file:

<kbd>app/code/community/Icepay/IceAdvanced/etc/config.xml</kbd>

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Icepay_IceAdvanced>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </Icepay_IceAdvanced>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <iceadvanced>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Icepay_IceAdvanced</module>
                    <frontName>icepayadvanced</frontName>
                </args>
            </iceadvanced>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <iceadvanced>
                    <file>iceadvanced.xml</file>
                </iceadvanced>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Icepay_IceAdvanced>
                    <files>
                        <default>Icepay_IceAdvanced.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Icepay_IceAdvanced>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <iceadvanced>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>iceadvanced/observer</class>
                        <method>sales_order_place_before</method>
                    </iceadvanced>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
            <custom_quote_process>
                <observers>
                    <iceadvanced>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>iceadvanced/observer</class>
                        <method>custom_quote_process</method>
                    </iceadvanced>
                </observers>
            </custom_quote_process>
        </events>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <iceadvanced>
                <class>Icepay_IceAdvanced_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>iceadvanced_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </iceadvanced>
            <iceadvanced_mysql4>
                <class>Icepay_IceAdvanced_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <icepay_issuerdata>
                        <table>icepay_issuerdata</table>
                    </icepay_issuerdata>
                    <icepay_pmdata>
                        <table>icepay_pmdata</table>
                    </icepay_pmdata>
                </entities>
            </iceadvanced_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <icepayadvanced_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Icepay_IceAdvanced</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </icepayadvanced_setup>
            <iceadvanced_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </iceadvanced_write>
            <iceadvanced_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </iceadvanced_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <iceadvanced>
                <class>Icepay_IceAdvanced_Block</class>
            </iceadvanced>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <iceadvanced>
                <class>Icepay_IceAdvanced_Helper</class>
            </iceadvanced>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <model_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <iceadvanced>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>iceadvanced/observer</class>
                        <method>model_save_before</method>
                    </iceadvanced>
                </observers>
            </model_save_before>
            <model_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <iceadvanced>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>iceadvanced/observer</class>
                        <method>model_save_after</method>
                    </iceadvanced>
                </observers>
            </model_save_after>
            <sales_order_payment_place_end>
                <observers>
                    <iceadvanced>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>iceadvanced/observer</class>
                        <method>sales_order_payment_place_end</method>
                    </iceadvanced>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_place_end>
        </events>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Icepay_IceAdvanced>
                    <files>
                        <default>Icepay_IceAdvanced.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Icepay_IceAdvanced>
            </modules>
        </translate>

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <iceadvanced translate="title" module="iceadvanced">
                                            <title>iceadvanced Settings</title>
                                        </iceadvanced>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Hopefully somebody could explain me what I am doing wrong. Before you blame me on the code, I did not create it in the first place.

Edit: After following [BJ Hoffpauir](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3133/bj-hoffpauir) guide; this is the output of the error.log

> 192.168.137.1 - - [17/Jul/2015:23:03:56 +0000] "POST /index.php/icepayadvanced/ajax/get_paymentmethods/key/21e4f55bb33ad6a323c50140bc5ef585/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1" 404 16910 "http://192.168.137.124/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/icecore/key/e96d9f50648cad8168ebf376470196ad/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Try to logout/login, if you then get an access denied, it is the same as http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285

Comment: I am sorry, I am still getting a 404. Nothing of the "Access Denied" anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ricardo, there are a few folders and files that may have had their permissions set to 777 when Magento originally created them that are updated by the patch.

I would suggest running through the following file and folder permissions doc from Magento to ensure that after you have installed the patch, you can confirm that all file and folder permissions are set to the [recommended security ACL's as defined in this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html).

NOTE : By default, that guide basically has you disabling the functionality of Magento Connect which is a good idea for your production sites - you don't want ANYONE installing software directly onto you productions system without testing and archival in a source code repository like git / hg / svn ... if you DO need to use that functionality, that guide provides instructions on how to temporarily loosen permissions enough to use the utility, then how to restore the more security settings when you are done.

Follow this guide, it will most likely solve your 404 issues.  If it does not, locate your Apache or Nginx web server log file and grep it for the 404 error - for example my logs are stored in

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

on my Ubuntu 14.04 system and when I run the command

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep 404
```

I might see output like the following:

```
[Sun Jul 12 21:39:54.824860 2015] [:error] [pid 1234] [client 10.10.10.10:51404] script '/var/www/html/script.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jul 12 21:39:54.824860 2015] [:error] [pid 1234] [client 10.10.10.10:51404] script '/var/www/html/script.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Paste what YOU find when you run that `cat` command replacing the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` with wherever YOUR web server log file is stored.  Edit your questions & paste what you find in your question and we can help you locate the source of the 404 error and the specific context in which it is generating the error.