# Third party extensions does not have adminhtml.xml to fix Access Denied errors after installing SUPEE-6285

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, adminhtml, acl, supee-6285

As posted [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285), the ACL resource must be find in adminhtml.xml, but in extension I have there is no such. However, the acl is defined in `community/3rdparty/extension/etc/config.xml` file. In addition, there are

```
community/3rdparty/extension/controllers/Catalog/product/itsfile.php
community/3rdparty/extension/controllers/Customer/itsfile.php
```

How would be the RESOURCE IDENTIFIER in such cases?

In which controller `protected function _isAllowed()` must be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extensions are probably very outdated or at least follow deprecated coding style. Before Magento 1.4, there was no `adminhtml.xml` and the ACL and admin menus were configured in `config.xml`.

**This still works for backwards compatibility**

As you can see in  `Mage_Admin_Model_Config`:

```
    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.0.0-alpha2
     * support backwards compatibility with config.xml
     */
    $aclConfig  = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/acl');
    if ($aclConfig) {
        $adminhtmlConfig->getNode()->extendChild($aclConfig, true);
    }
    $menuConfig = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('adminhtml/menu');
    if ($menuConfig) {
        $adminhtmlConfig->getNode()->extendChild($menuConfig, true);
    }
```

The nodes `adminhtml/acl` and `adminhtml/menu` from `config.xml` are merged into the adminhtml configuration. So you will find the resource identifiers in  `config.xml` and theoretically can add them there as well. But I'd recommend creating a custom module with its own `adminhtml.xml` instead to add the missing resources.

As for your second question, the `_isAllowed()` method must be added to every controller that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`