# Why are my users being denied access when permission is granted?

Tags: admin, permissions

I have a "Sales Rep" Role with limited access (basically just Orders, Customers, and a Sales Report page).

The problem is that on some of these pages, their access is still partially limited despite having permissions granted in the Permission Role Resources menu.

For example, they are denied access when trying to Delete an Invoice or access our Sales Reports Dashboard.

[image: Access Denied Image]

## How can I determine how these permissions are being overridden?

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?  Was this after applying SUPEE-6285? See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/73646/2190

Comment: This was it. I'm on 1.9, but there were several 3rd party extensions that I had to add the `_isAllowed` method. All is well now. If you'd like to add your comment as an answer with a brief explanation, I'd be glad to accept it.