# Magento extension admin tabs return 404

Tags: patches, extensions, 404

I have an extension which used to work and somehow either because i added in .htaccess

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteBase /nescr/
>   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteRule . /nescr/index.php [L]
> ```

or because of something else? what could be? it stoped working before i put the patch on .it returns now 404 in the admin when open the extension tabs. 
What could be done? I tried to empty cache, index, compilation...take away the code but nothing works!
my config.xml is as follows

> 

1.0.3

```
<global>

    <blocks>
        <followupemail>
            <class>HN_Followupemail_Block</class>
        </followupemail>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <followupemail>
            <class>HN_Followupemail_Helper</class>
        </followupemail>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <followupemail>
            <class>HN_Followupemail_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>followupemail_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </followupemail>
        <followupemail_mysql4>
            <class>HN_Followupemail_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <rule>
                    <table>hn_followupemail_rule</table>
                </rule>
                <mail>
                    <table>hn_followupemail_mail</table>
                </mail>
                <track>
                    <table>hn_followupemail_track</table>
                </track>
                <followupemail>
                    <table>hn_event_followupemail</table>
                </followupemail>
            </entities>
        </followupemail_mysql4>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <followupemail_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>HN_Followupemail</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </followupemail_setup>
        <followupemail_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </followupemail_write>
        <followupemail_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </followupemail_read>
    </resources>

    <template>
        <email>
            <fue>
                <label>Ticket information</label>
                <file>fue.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </fue>
        </email>
    </template>
    <events>
        <salesrule_rule_get_coupon_types>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/observer</class>
                    <method>addCouponType</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </salesrule_rule_get_coupon_types>

        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_order</class>
                    <method>orderCommitListener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_customer</class>
                    <method>listener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
        <newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_newsletter</class>
                    <method>newsletterSubscriberList</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </newsletter_subscriber_save_commit_after>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_customerlogin</class>
                    <method>listener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_customerlogout</class>
                    <method>listener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <!-- <customer_save_after> -->
        <!-- <followupemail_observer> -->
        <!-- <class>followupemail/observer</class> -->
        <!-- <method>customerSaveListener</method> -->
        <!-- </followupemail_observer> -->
        <!-- </customer_save_after> -->
        <wishlist_share>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_wishlist</class>
                    <method>wishlistShareListener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </wishlist_share>
        <wishlist_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <followupemail_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>followupemail/rule_condition_wishlistadditem</class>
                    <method>wishlistProductAddListener</method>
                </followupemail_observer>
            </observers>
        </wishlist_product_add_after>
    </events>
</global>


<frontend>
    <routers>
        <followupemail>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>HN_Followupemail</module>
                <frontName>followupemail</frontName>
            </args>
        </followupemail>

    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <followupemail>
                <file>hn_followupemail.xml</file>
            </followupemail>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <followupemail before="Mage_Adminhtml">HN_Followupemail_Adminhtml
                    </followupemail>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <followupemail translate="title" module="followupemail">
            <title>Follow Up Email</title>
            <sort_order>130</sort_order>
            <children>
                <rule translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Manage Rules</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_rule/index</action>
                </rule>
                <mail_log translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Mail Log</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_mail/index</action>
                </mail_log>
                <link_tack translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Link tracking</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_track/index</action>
                </link_tack>
                <coupon translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Coupon</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_coupon/index</action>
                </coupon>

            </children>
        </followupemail>
    </menu>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <followupemail>
                <file>hn_followupemail.xml</file>
            </followupemail>
        </updates>
    </layout>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <followupemail translate="title" module="followupemail">
                                        <title>Follow up Email Settings</title>
                                    </followupemail>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <followupemail translate="title" module="followupemail">
            <title>Follow Up Email</title>
            <sort_order>130</sort_order>
            <children>
                <rule translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Manage Rules</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_rule/index</action>
                </rule>
                <mail_log translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Mail Log</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_mail/index</action>
                </mail_log>
                <link_tack translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Link tracking</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_track/index</action>
                </link_tack>
                <coupon translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Coupon</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_coupon/index</action>
                </coupon>

            </children>
        </followupemail>
                </children>


            </admin>

            <followupemail translate="title" module="followupemail">
            <title>Follow Up Email</title>
            <sort_order>130</sort_order>
            <children>
                <rule translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Manage Rules</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_rule/index</action>
                </rule>
                <mail_log translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Mail Log</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_mail/index</action>
                </mail_log>
                <link_tack translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Link tracking</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_track/index</action>
                </link_tack>
                <coupon translate="title" module="followupemail">
                    <title>Coupon</title>
                    <action>followupemail/adminhtml_coupon/index</action>
                </coupon>

            </children>
        </followupemail>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<default>
    <followupemailevent>
        <order>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_order</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </order>
        <customer_register>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_customer</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </customer_register>
        <customer_groupchange>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_customergroupchange</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </customer_groupchange>
        <customer_login>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_customerlogin</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </customer_login>
        <customerlogout>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_customerlogout</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </customerlogout>
        <newsletter_signup>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_newsletter</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </newsletter_signup>
        <wishlist_share>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_wishlist</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </wishlist_share>
        <wishlist_item_add>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_wishlistadditem</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </wishlist_item_add>
        <abandoned_cart>
            <model>followupemail/rule_condition_abandonedcart</model>
            <active>1</active>
        </abandoned_cart>
        <customer_birthday>
            <model>followupemail/_rule_condition_birthday</model>
            <active>1</active>

        </customer_birthday>
    </followupemailevent>
    <followupemail>
        <general>
            <change_status>1</change_status>
            <email_sender>sales</email_sender>
            <qty_sync>1</qty_sync>
            <delivery_confirmed>0</delivery_confirmed>
            <low_stock_notification>1</low_stock_notification>
            <low_stock_number>10</low_stock_number>
            <show_followupemail_successpage>1</show_followupemail_successpage>
        </general>
    </followupemail>

</default>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <seding_queue_followupemail>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>followupemail/observer::scheduledSend</model>
            </run>
        </seding_queue_followupemail>
    </jobs>

    <jobs>
        <collect_abandoned_cart>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>followupemail/rule_condition_abandonedcart::scheduleCollectAbandonedCart</model>
            </run>

        </collect_abandoned_cart>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Denied errors after installing SUPEE-6285](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285)

Comment: checked it  but it stopped working before i put the patch on but thank you

Comment: Sorry I misread that

Comment: Can we see your system.xml and adminhtml.xml?