# Access Denied errors after installing security patches

Tags: security, admin-panel, user-roles

i created some user and roles in magento

i logged in with that username and password.

but i am getting message "Access Denied".

it was working before, after we installed the security patches , it happened.

i found solution here : [Access Denied errors after installing SUPEE-6285](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285)

but i did't understood the line here :

"The only solution is to patch the extensions and add this method to all their admin controllers:" means is i have to add that code in controllers? if so i want to know in which file i need to add...

please explain me what actually i need to solve this

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as Baby in Magento 2 is seeking clarification on one of the points in the referenced question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download updates of your extensions, or you could apply the code yourself. Most likely you have to change the adminhtml.xml in the modules that are not working.

Comment: there it mentioned we have to add following code :


protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}

i want to know in controllers, in which file i have to edit ?

Comment: thanks a lot , this is the file i need to edit : app/code/local/extension/controllers/Adminhtml

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 did it work?

Comment: yes i followed that link, it worked......

Answer (score 0):

we need to look at extension folder : app/code/local/extension/controllers/Adminhtml and than we have to add the code as in this link : [Access Denied errors after installing SUPEE-6285](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285)