# 404 Error Page not found error on extension admin route update Installing SUPEE - 6788

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, supee-6788

I have installed supee 6788 patch in my store. I have several extensions in my store.

I have just updated admin route as per magento APPSEC-1034, addressing bypassing custom admin URL but it gives me 404 page not found error in my third party extensions.

I have changed config.xml from

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <orderseraser>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Wyomind_Orderseraser</module>
                    <frontName>orderseraser</frontName>
                </args>
            </orderseraser>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

to

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <orderseraser after="Mage_Adminhtml">Wyomind_Orderseraser_Adminhtml</orderseraser>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

but it gives admin url 404.

I have tried in several extensions but its giving me same error in all other extensions.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285

Comment: Sorry, I have already tried that but its not working. My question is reagrding admin route and supee -6788.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this script and see if it identifies any more issues with the routes and controllers, there are other benefits as well to running the script - one being the "whitelisting" of blocks for the site.

[Magento® SUPEE-6788 Developer Toolbox](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox)

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend the developer toolbox from github. you can just let it analyze and apply the fixes yourself.
But if you want to do it manually, you have to move some directories and edit some more files.
Move

```
/path/to/magento/app/code/local/Wyomind/Orderseraser/controllers/Adminhtml
```

to

```
/path/to/magento/app/code/local/Wyomind/Orderseraser/controllers/Adminhtml/Orderseraser
```

Next, in `app/code/local/Wyomind/Orderseraser/etc/config.xml`

change:                        `<action>orderseraser/adminhtml_orderseraser</action>`

to:                        `<action>adminhtml/orderseraser_orderseraser</action>`

in `/app/code/local/Wyomind/Orderseraser/etc/adminhtml.xml`

change:                        `<action>orderseraser/adminhtml_orderseraser</action>`

to:                        `<action>adminhtml/orderseraser_orderseraser</action>`

in `/app/code/local/Wyomind/Orderseraser/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderseraserController.php`

change:
`class Wyomind_Orderseraser_Adminhtml_OrderseraserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {`

to: `class Wyomind_Orderseraser_Adminhtml_Orderseraser_OrderseraserController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {`

Check also the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/orderseraser.xml`

and swap any nodes with adminhtml, i.e. if you have

```
<orderseraser_adminhtml_orderseraser_index>
```

change to    `<adminhtml_orderseraser_orderseraser_index>`

And I think that's it for this 1 extension.. hope you can get it to work.