# Magento 1.9.2.1 custom modules are showing 404 after SUPEE-6788

Tags: adminhtml, supee-6788, magento-1.9.2.1

I have uploaded patch **SUPEE-6788** on **Magento 1.9.2.1** and tried the following:

- Using [This](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox) file I have fixed all the modules through command line after uploading the patch.
- I have also fixed whitelisting issues using the same file.
- Tried logging out of admin and re logged in.
- Removed all cache from /var/cache.
- Reindexed my store.

But still all custom modules are showing page 404 in admin.

**Note**: All the code of custom module is as per [This Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/88559/39707)

The functionality is working fine on frontend but admin pages of these modules are not working.

As I have checked after using the FIX code the action in config is the same before and after fix. Check below:

```
<menu>
      <banners module="banners">
        <title>Banners</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <banners module="banners">
            <title>Manage Banners</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_banners/adminhtml_banners</action>
          </banners>
        </children>
      </banners>
    </menu>
```

> Update 1

After applying changes mentioned by Kunj following is my action code and controller file location:

```
<action>adminhtml/banners/banners</action>
```

Controller for above action :

*`app/code/local/{My_Package}/Banners/controllers/Adminhtml/Banners/BannersController.php`*

I have re-indexed, cleared cache, Logged out and logged in but it still shows page 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `action` should be like this:

```
<action>adminhtml/banners</action>
```

And as per action your file path should be like this:

```
/path/to/magento/app/code/local/{module package name}/Banners/controllers/Adminhtml/Banners/IndexController.php
```

Comment: I have added update 1 to my question as per your provided solution.

Comment: As per your banners module's admin controller file structure, your action should be like This:  `<action>adminhtml/banners_banners/index</action>` `banners` is your  `controller` and `index` is `action` which located in `app/code/local/{My_Package}/Banners/controllers/Adminhtml/Banners/BannersController.php` file.

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!

Comment: can you also check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226180/magento-1-9-2-1-module-without-package-name-is-showing-404-after-supee-6788) question?