# Magento 1.9.2.1 module without package name is showing 404 after SUPEE-6788

Tags: module, adminhtml, supee-6788, magento-1.9.2.1

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1 and after installing SUPEE-6788 I have fixed all of the affected modules as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225641/magento-1-9-2-1-custom-modules-are-showing-404-after-supee-6788).

All of my modules (That has a package directory eg: "app/code/local/{module_package}/{module_name}" ) which were not working after installation of this patch are now working fine now.

I have a module which is working fine without SUPEE-6788 and it has no package folder.

Following are the details of the only module which is not working in admin and giving page 404:

Path to module : `app/code/{code_pool}/Rewardpoints` (where *Rewardpoints* is the module name)

Some of the code from Config.xml:

```
<modules>
    <Rewardpoints>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Customer />
            <Mage_Checkout />
        </depends>
    </Rewardpoints>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <rewardpoints before="Mage_Adminhtml">Rewardpoints_Adminhtml</rewardpoints>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <rewardpoints>
                <file>rewardpoints.xml</file>
            </rewardpoints>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <menu>
        <rewardpoints translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
            <title>Reward Points</title>
            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
            <children>
                <stats translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                    <title>Statistics</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/rewardpoints_stats</action>
                </stats>
                <clientpoints translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                    <title>Client points</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/rewardpoints_clientpoints</action>
                </clientpoints>
                <config translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                    <title>Configuration</title>
                    <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/rewardpoints</action>
                </config>
            </children>
        </rewardpoints>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <rewardpoints module="rewardpoints">
                        <title>Reward Points</title>
                        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <stats translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                                <title>Statistics</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </stats>
                            <clientpoints translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                                <title>Client points</title>
                                <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            </clientpoints>
                            <config translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                                <title>Configuration</title>
                                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </rewardpoints>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <rewardpoints_adminform>
                                <title>Configuration</title>
                            </rewardpoints_adminform>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <rewardpoints>
                                        <title>Reward Points</title>
                                    </rewardpoints>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <rewardpoints translate="title">
                                <title>Reward Points</title>
                                <sort_order>41</sort_order>
                            </rewardpoints>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

Path to controllers:

```
app/code/{code_pool}/Rewardpoints/controllers/Adminhtml/Rewardpoints/StatsController.php

app/code/{code_pool}/Rewardpoints/controllers/Adminhtml/Rewardpoints/ClientpointsController.php
```

Class for StatsController.php:

```
class Rewardpoints_Adminhtml_Rewardpoints_StatsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
```

Class for ClientpointsController.php:

```
class Rewardpoints_Adminhtml_Rewardpoints_ClientpointsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
```

IndexAction Function in StatsController.php:

```
public function indexAction() {
            $this->_initAction()
                ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('rewardpoints/adminhtml_stats'))
                ->renderLayout();
    }
```

IndexAction Function in ClientpointsController.php:

```
public function indexAction() {
            $this->_initAction()
                ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('rewardpoints/adminhtml_clientpoints'))
                ->renderLayout();
    }
```

Content in app/etc/modules/RewardPoints.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rewardpoints>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>{{code_pool}}</codePool>
        </Rewardpoints>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Note 1:** Even `die();` function is not working in the above IndexAction methods.

**Note 2:** The module is working fine in admin without SUPEE-6788 Patch.

There is no layout xml file for adminhtml

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: check my answer it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only this Acl:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <rewardpoints>
                                    <title>Reward Points</title>
                                </rewardpoints>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
                <rewardpoints module="rewardpoints">
                    <title>Reward Points</title>
                    <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <stats translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                            <title>Statistics</title>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        </stats>
                        <clientpoints translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                            <title>Client points</title>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                        </clientpoints>
                        <config translate="title" module="rewardpoints">
                            <title>Configuration</title>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </rewardpoints>
                <customer>
                    <children>
                        <rewardpoints translate="title">
                            <title>Reward Points</title>
                            <sort_order>41</sort_order>
                        </rewardpoints>
                    </children>
                </customer>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Remove others and clear cache then try again.

For specification:
   This is for your setting configuration fields:

```
<system>
   <children>
      <config>
         <children>
            <rewardpoints>
               <title>Reward Points</title>
            </rewardpoints>
         </children>
      </config>
   </children>
</system>
```

And this is if you have added action to customer action:

```
<customer>
   <children>
      <rewardpoints translate="title">
         <title>Reward Points</title>
         <sort_order>41</sort_order>
      </rewardpoints>
   </children>
</customer>
```

Comment: What about "rewardpoints_adminform"?

Comment: Is that loading directly in admin and is that controller?

Comment: I have made the changes mentioned by you, flushed cache. Still its not working

Comment: Do you have `"IndexAction"`  `function` in `StatsController.php` AND `ClientpointsController.php` files?

Comment: Yes there is IndexAction Function in both of these controllers, I have tried adding die("testing"); even this is not working. While in other modules die(); is working fine in IndexAction function

Comment: Can you share `StatsController.php` file content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77566/discussion-between-wasiq-shahrukh-and-kunj).

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: `protected function _isAllowed()
 {
  return true;
 }` Add this code in your `StatsController.php` file then clear `cache`,  check after that.

Comment: If it is working, then you need to add permission code in your controller.

Comment: Added _isAllowed() in my controller this is still showing 404

Comment: I have added new Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add ACL inside `<adminhtml>`:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <rewardpoints>
                    <title>Rewardpoints Module</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>                     
                </rewardpoints>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

**Check those points also:**

Under controllers folder, you have an Adminhtml folder
controllers names are named correctly and action method is called successfully

admin layout folder contain the right action handler `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your_module.xml` which call the right block name.

ACL node is defined correctly in `adminhtml.xml` or `config.xml`
`_isAllowed()` method is not overrided and if it's the case try to check `$resource` parameter of `isAllowed()` method

clean the cache and check.

Comment: I have updated my question with acl code and there is no admin layout xml for this module.

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong in your module, Where is "module package"?

I mean your module should like this:

`app/code/{code_pool}/{Module Package}/Rewardpoints/Adminhtml/Rewardpoints/StatsController.php`

`app/code/{code_pool}/{Module Package}/Rewardpoints/Adminhtml/Rewardpoints/ClientpointsController.php`

Your Admin controller file path should be Like this:

`app/code/local/{{Module Package}}/Rewardpoints/controllers/Adminhtml`

Class also should be like this:

```
class {{Module Package}}_Rewardpoints_Adminhtml_Rewardpoints_StatsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action


class {{Module Package}}_Rewardpoints_Adminhtml_Rewardpoints_ClientpointsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
```

Comment: I have mentioned this in my question heading itself. It is perfectly working with this structure (Without any package), That's why I am confused how to make it work with SUPEE-6788

Comment: What have you added in `<modules>
        <{{Module Package}}_{{ModuleName}}>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </{{Module Package}}_{{ModuleName}}>
    </modules>` for this?

Comment: And what have you added in `app/etc/modules/`?

Comment: RewardPoints.xml updated my question with this file code and added <modules> part of config.xml

Comment: Ok, let me try with module

Comment: You should change in your module and add {{Module Package}}.

Comment: I have changed the files and structure accordingly but it still wont work. I have now uploaded the backed up code which was taken before applying fix using fixSUPEE6788.php file(as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox))

Comment: Please share your updated code

Comment: Please provide some link where I can upload the whole module for you to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77620/discussion-between-kunj-and-wasiq-shahrukh).