# Access Denied for Custom Module for specific role

Tags: permissions, acl, role, access

I've created one role and provide rights for my custom module using ***System->Permissions->Role***. When any user from that role logs into system, gets access denied for my custom module. My config.xml looks this

```
<acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <vendor translate="title" module="vendor">
                            <title>Vendor</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <vendor translate="title">
                                    <title>Manage Vendor</title>
                                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                </vendor>
                            </children>
                        </vendor>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
```

**And my adminhtml.xml looks like this**

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vendor translate="title" module="vendor">
                                        <title>Vendor Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                                    </vendor>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you installed any security patch in the site?

Comment: If you recently installed any security patch , please look at this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285

Comment: I've not installed any security patch. And my controller has isAllowed function also. protected function _isAllowed() 
    { 
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('vendor/kitchoff_vendor_vendor'); 
    }

Comment: remove the acl from `config.xml` use one acl only..

Comment: If I remove acl from config.xml, then also I get Access denied when I login from role defined. In my controller, I've written code for method _isAllowed like this protected function _isAllowed() 
    { 
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('vendor/kitchoff_vendor_vendor'); 
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem resolved.

By modifying `_isAllowed()` function like following

`protected function _isAllowed() { return true; }`

Answer (score 3):

> Problem resolved.
>
> By modifying _isAllowed() function like following
>
> protected function _isAllowed() { return true; }

It's a very bad decision. In you case right way is:

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('system/vendor');
}
```

Comment: this's a work around and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your adminhtml.xml/config.xml(don't specify in both file) file may contains wrong xml element hierarchy. it must be match with current hierarchy of menu. In your case it should be like this

```
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vendor translate="title" module="vendor">
                        <title>Vendor</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <kitchoff_vendor_vendor translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Vendor</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </kitchoff_vendor_vendor>
                        </children>
                    </vendor>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```