# Getting Access Denied for module

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, acl, third-party-module

**Issue**

I have a module that allows users to login as the customer (Spadar_Login). This modules uses user permissions. It works for admin roles and it prevents access to roles without permission. The issue is roles that are given permission do not work.  It receives "Access denied" as though it did not have permission.

**Troubleshooting**

Cache has been cleared and disabled, compilation disabled, logged out and in.

The message is displayed on the admin side, for an admin route calling an admin controller. I removed any `isAllowed()` check in controllers. The controller being called has had all code removed and the issue still occurs, which tells me the access is denied before it reaches the controller. I tried removing the `acl` tag in the config.xml but the issue still persists. I have triple checked the the user is in the right role, and that the role has permission to the user.

**Code**

Here is the `acl` in the `etc/config.xml`

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <customer>
                        <children>
                            <login>
                                <title>Login as Customer</title>
                            </login>
                        </children>
                    </customer>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Here is the route

```
<admin>
    <routers>
      <spadarloginadmin>
          <use>admin</use>
          <args>
              <module>Spadar_Login_Adminhtml</module>
              <frontName>spadarloginadmin</frontName>
          </args>
      </spadarloginadmin>
   </routers>
</admin>
```

What is causing this user role not to be able to access this controller?

Comment: Are you getting "Access denied in backend" ?

Comment: Yes, it's a backend button, on the admin, calling an admin controller. Will update to specify.

Comment: pls check the answer i posted & let me know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complete credits for  **@fschmengler** for this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285)

add this method in admin controllers:

if you have an ACL resource defined in `etc/adminhtml.xml` , than

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('ENTER RESOURCE IDENTIFIER HERE');
}
```

Comment: You first statement is really bad in terms of security, admin controllers should always have an ACL resource defined and use the second bit of code you pasted.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i will update my answer soon.

Comment: I used the second code block and it worked for me which looks secure to me.

Comment: @Goose Glad that it helped you.