# How to give custom acces permissions for admin users(roles) to an extension magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, permissions, user-roles, acl

I have created a admin user in magento and give certain access permissions, and i have an extension called support ticket, i gave user role access to this extension, when i logged in that particular user i am getting an error called access denied for that support ticket extension, when i login as admin it is working fine, and when i changed user role permission from custom to all, every thing is working as expected, but i need to give only this particular access permission,what can i do ?[image]

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <support_ticket_ultimate translate="title" module="supportticket">
                                        <title>Support Ticket Ultimate Section</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                    </support_ticket_ultimate>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to explain a bit what @Sander Mangel said in his answer:

> - make sure the Adminhtml controller of the module has a _isAllowed method

Look for files like this:

```
/app/code/community/your/module/controllers/Adminhtml/SomeController.php
```

and make sure there's a method that looks like this inside every admin controller:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('your_module/resource_you_need');
}
```

A [recent security](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73631/9392) patch makes it so that controllers without the `_isAllowed` method do not work. That answer also says that this works if the module has implemented ACL in `etc/adminhtml.xml` and since you say you added the appropiate permission to the user role, it sounds like yours does. In case it doesn't, just `return true;` from the method, but this allows access to any admin user.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of thinks you can check

- make sure the Adminhtml controller of the module has a `_isAllowed` method
- check if the path in the `_isAllowed` method matches you ACL in the `adminhtml.xml` file
- make sure the cache is cleared after creating the role

Comment: I have checked in the code but i couldn't identify this, below shows  the extension i have used http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/support-ticket-2.html?utm_campaign=bazaarvoice&utm_medium=SearchVoice&utm_source=AskAndAnswer&utm_content=Default for support ticket, can you help me on this?

Comment: I would advice you to contact the module developer for support. They will know what to do

Comment: Already done that, but no response from them, i am checking from my side is there any fixes possible or not with this extension, but frankly i am new to this magento admin Acl

Comment: check if the module code has xml part related to ACL.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution is to patch the extensions and add this method to all their admin controllers:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```