# Version not changed, after applying patch SUPEE 7405 1.1

Tags: patches, supee-7405, version, ce-1.9.2.3, ce-1.9.2.4

I applied latest patch (PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.3_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-46-32) to a fresh magento 1.9.2.3 installation

The compiler has never run, all caches are disabled

The patch was applied successfully but after logging in back to back-end I still see 1.9.2.3 on the footer, while it should be 1.9.2.4

I reverted and reapplied the patch successfully but no luck.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patches are meant to be applied on older versions to only fix specific issues without updating Magento. As such, they do not increase the version number.

If you are already on the latest version you can update Magento with a patch release like 1.9.2.4 **instead** of applying the patch with the shell script.

The difference is:

- an update replaces all core files and bumps the version number
- a patch only changes specific lines in specific files

Comment: so, in which cases you would recommend updating vs patching and vice versa?
in particular should I update or patch from 1.9.2.2  to 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4 ?

Comment: Always patch immediately. I only recommend an update instead of a patch if you are already on the latest version and the new version *only* contains the patch and no other changes (this was the case for 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4). See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80058/should-i-upgrade-or-patch-magento/80062#80062

Answer (score 2):

Although you could install 1.9.2.4 instead of the patch, since you're already at 1.9.2.3, be aware that there is a slight difference. In 1.9.2.4 CURLOPT_SSLVERSION has been added as an allowed parameter in Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl.

Some more info about the SUPEE 7405 1.1 patch can be found here; https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/002705a84fd409cb5c2c

Comment: Ah, again they sneaked something in, just as in 1.9.2.2. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Patch should not increase magento version. New magento version can contain more changes than in patch. Security patches are necessary only to close known security issues.